# Unable to reimport Grails project into GGTS / STS?

Tags: eclipse, grails

I have copied a grails project to the workspace folder -
and try to import. The following error is shown:

Invalid project description.
OK
C:\Users...\workspace-ggts-3.5.1.RELEASE\ overlaps the location of another project: ''

How can I can clean the workspace correctly (delete the project properly) so that this message does not appear? I did ensure that the project name under .projects did
not exist prior to import - but message still indicates an overlap?

I then open project and Run As Grails Command (run-app).Grails home is set to: C:\grails-1.3.7\ -
and get

Base Directory: C:...
Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 470ms.
C:... does not appear to be part of a Grails application.
The following commands are supported outside of a project:
    add-proxy
    clear-proxy
    create-app
    create-plugin
    help
    list-plugins
    package-plugin
    plugin-info
    remove-proxy
    set-proxy
Run 'grails help' for a complete list of available scripts.

Note that I had imported the project successfully before (as a Grails project) and 
have deleted since etc.
I have also tried moving to other folder which I do not want to do.

How can I resolve the above?

Thank you
Simon

Comment: Do you get the same problem with most recent GGTS 3.6.0 ? https://spring.io/tools/ggts/all

Comment: Yes - I import a project then delete the project then reimport the project and the following error occurs: Invalid project description. OK C:\Users...\workspace-ggts-3.6.0.RELEASE\ overlaps the location of another project: '' Seems that a project is not deleted correctly?